# JObject error "Property with the same name already exists on object"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Generally I have had no issue using JSON.NET to deserialize JSON to a dynamic object. However the JSON below is causing the error

> Can not add property consent to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.

I have checked the JSON against JSONLint and it appears valid. What am I missing here?

Code

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

JSON

```
{
"DataFields": {
    "preamble": {
    },
    "applicant": {
        "description": {
            "count": "1"
        },
        "details": {
            "title": null,
            "first_name": null,
            "middle_name": null,
            "surname": null
        },
        "property": {
            "address": {
                "line1": null,
                "line2": null,
                "line3": null,
                "town": null,
                "county": null,
                "postcode": null
            },
            "solicitor": {
                "name": null,
                "address": {
                    "line1": null,
                    "line2": null,
                    "line3": null,
                    "town": null,
                    "county": null,
                    "postcode": null
                },
                "contact": {
                    "email": null,
                    "reference_number": null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    "boundaries": {
        "description": {
        },
        "location": {
            "left": null,
            "right": null,
            "back": null,
            "front": null,
            "maintenance": null,
            "movement": null,
            "movement_details": null,
            "ownership": null,
            "additional_land": null,
            "additional_land_details": null,
            "flying_freehold": null,
            "flying_freehold_details": null
            }
        },
    "discom": {
        "descritpion": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "complaint": {
            "received": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "made": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
                }
            }
        },
    "notices": {
        "sentrec": {
            "question": null,
            "upload": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "negotiations": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
            }
        },
    "guarantees": {
        "individual": {
            "foundation_newbuild": null,
            "foundation_newbuild_upload": null,
            "damp_course": null,
            "damp_course_upload": null,
            "glazing_roofing": null,
            "glazing_roofing_upload": null,
            "electrical": null,
            "electrical_upload": null,
            "roofing": null,
            "roofing_upload": null,
            "infestation": null,
            "infestation_upload": null,
            "heating": null,
            "heating_upload": null,
            "underpinning": null,
            "underpinning_upload": null,
            "other": null,
            "other_type": null,
            "other_upload": null,
            "written_details": null
        },
        "misc": {
            "written_details_upload": null
        },
        "summary": {
            "originals": null,
            "claims": null,
            "claims_upload": null
            }
        },
    "central_heating": {
        "description": {
            "installed": null
        },
        "details": {
            "condition": {
                "working": null,
                "details": null,
                "type": null,
                "date": null,
                "unknown": null,
                "completion": null
            },
            "service": {
                "year": null,
                "unknown": null,
                "copy": null
                }
            }
        },
    "services": {
        "connected": {
            "gas": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "meter": null
                    }
                },
            "electric": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "meter": null
                    }
                },
            "mainwater": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "stop_cock": null,
                    "meter": null
                    }
                },
            "maindrain": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "meter": null
                    }
                },
            "telephone": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null
                    }
                },
            "broadband": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null
                    }
                },
            "cable": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null
                    }
                },
            "satellite_tv": {
                "question": null,
                "supplier": {
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null
                    }
                }
            },
        "water": {
            "charge": {
                "water": {
                    "latest": null
                },
                "sewerage": {
                    "latest": null
                    }
                },
            "meter": {
                "question": null,
                "foul": null,
                "surface": null
                }
            },
        "your_property": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "neighbours_property": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "agreement": {
            "question": null,
            "copy": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "drain_problems": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "septic_cesspit": {
            "septic": null,
            "sewage": null,
            "cesspool": null,
            "drainage": {
                "septic_tank": null,
                "number": null,
                "year_last_emptied": null,
                "year_installed": null,
                "year_treated": null,
                "outside_property": null,
                "plan_upload": null
                }
            },
        "electricity": {
            "question": null,
            "tested": {
                "year": null,
                "copy": null
            },
            "rewire": {
                "question": null,
                "certificates": {
                    "bs7671": null,
                    "compliance": null,
                    "completion": null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    "neighbours": {
        "contribution": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "repair": {
            "question": null,
            "details": {
                "information": null,
                "organiser": null,
                "charging": null
                }
            },
        "property": {
            "question": null,
            "details": {
                "information": null,
                "objections": null,
                "details": null
                }
            },
        "your_property": {
            "question": null,
            "objections": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "notice": {
            "question": null,
            "copy": null,
            "details": null
            }
        },
    "arrangements": {
        "description": {
        },
        "access": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null,
            "payment": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "neighbours": {
                "question": null,
                "details": {
                    "details": null
                    }
                },
            "other": {
                "question": null,
                "details": {
                    "details": null
                },
                "arrangements": {
                    "rights_of_light": null,
                    "rights_of_support": null,
                    "customary_rights": null,
                    "mines_and_minerals": null,
                    "chancel_repair": null,
                    "take_things": null,
                    "details": null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    "occupiers": {
        "description": {
            "seller_at_property": null,
            "vacant": null,
            "occupants": null
        },
        "details": {
            "number": null,
            "other": {
                "name": null,
                "age": null
            },
            "rights": {
                "agreed_to_leave": null,
                "agreed_to_sign": null,
                "vacation_evidence": null,
                "tenants_or_lodgers": null,
                "tenants_or_lodgers_details": null
                }
            }
        },
    "changes": {
        "description": {
        },
        "building": {
            "question": null,
            "works": {
                "details": null,
                "year": null,
                "permission": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "title": {
                    "question": null,
                    "restriction": {
                        "question": null,
                        "consent": {
                            "explanation": null,
                            "name": null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                "insurance_policy": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                    }
                }
            },
        "change": {
            "use_question": {
                "question": null,
                "changes_change_use": {
                    "year": null,
                    "permission": {
                        "question": null,
                        "upload": null
                    },
                    "regulations_approved": {
                        "question": null,
                        "upload": null
                    },
                    "title_restriction_question": {
                        "question": null,
                        "changes_change_use_title_restriction": {
                            "question": null,
                            "consent": {
                                "explanation": null,
                                "contact": null
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    "insurance_policy": {
                        "question": null,
                        "upload": null
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        "sub": {
            "question": null,
            "division": {
                "year": null,
                "permission": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "title": {
                    "question": null,
                    "restriction": {
                        "question": null,
                        "consent": {
                            "explanation": null,
                            "contact": null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                "insurance_policy": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                    }
                }
            },
        "conversionquestion": {
            "question": null
        },
        "conversion": {
            "year": null,
            "permission": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
            },
            "regulations_approved": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
            },
            "title_restrictionquestion": {
                "question": null
            },
            "title_restriction": {
                "question": null,
                "consent": {
                    "explanation": null,
                    "contact": null
                    }
                },
            "insurance_policy": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
                }
            },
        "business": {
            "question": null,
            "activity": {
                "year": null,
                "permission": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "title": {
                    "restrictions": null,
                    "restriction": {
                        "question": null,
                        "consent": {
                            "explanation": null,
                            "contact": null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                "insurance_policy": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                    }
                }
            },
        "underpinningquestion": {
            "question": null
        },
        "underpinning": {
            "year": null,
            "permission": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
            },
            "regulations_approved": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
            },
            "title": {
                "question": null,
                "restriction": {
                    "question": null,
                    "consent": {
                        "explanation": null,
                        "contact": null
                        }
                    }
                },
            "insurance_policy": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
                }
            },
        "solar": {
            "question": null,
            "panels": {
                "year": null,
                "permission": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "title": {
                    "question": null,
                    "restriction": {
                        "question": null,
                        "consent": {
                            "explanation": null,
                            "contact": null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                "insurance_policy": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "ownership": {
                    "question": null
                },
                "lease": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                    }
                }
            },
        "replace": {
            "question": null,
            "window_roof": {
                "year": null,
                "permission": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "title": {
                    "question": null,
                    "restriction": {
                        "consent": null,
                        "consent": {
                            "explanation": null,
                            "contact": null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                "insurance_policy": {
                    "question": null,
                    "upload": null
                },
                "certificate_regulations": {
                    "question": null
                    }
                }
            },
        "air_conditioning": {
            "installed": null,
            "year": null
        },
        "satellite_dish": {
            "installed": null,
            "year": null
        },
        "central_heating": {
            "installed": null,
            "details": {
                "year": null,
                "upload": null
                }
            },
        "unfinished": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "breaches": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "unresolved": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
            }
        },
    "conservatory": {
        "description": {
            "question": null
        },
        "details": {
            "public": null,
            "ground_level": null,
            "domestic_purpose": null,
            "volume": null,
            "height": null,
            "boundary": null,
            "area": null,
            "roof_materials": null,
            "safety_glass": null,
            "sleeping_accommodation": null,
            "access": null,
            "heating": null,
            "drainage": null,
            "build_date": null,
            "building_regulations": null,
            "building_regulations_copy": null
            }
        },
    "planning": {
        "buildingcontrol": {
            "private": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "listed_building": {
                "listed": null,
                "conservation": null,
                "upload": null
            },
            "grants": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
            },
            "gas_installation": {
                "question": null,
                "upload": null
            },
            "proposed_development": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "treequestion": {
                "question": null
            },
            "tree": {
                "question": null,
                "local_authority": {
                    "question": null
                    }
                },
            "drain_alterations": {
                "question": null,
                "year": null
                }
            }
        },
    "expenses": {
        "property_costs": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
            }
        },
    "sale_mechanics": {
        "chain": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "mortgage": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "deposit": {
            "question": null
        },
        "excess": {
            "question": null
            }
        },
    "moving": {
        "description": {
            "special": null,
            "date": null
            }
        },
    "environmental": {
        "description": {
        },
        "flooding": {
            "question": null,
            "details": {
                "date_and_location": null,
                "ground_water": null,
                "sewer_flooding": null,
                "surface_water": null,
                "coastal_flooding": null,
                "river_flooding": null,
                "other": null,
                "description": null
            },
            "risk": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
                }
            },
        "contamination_land_fill": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "property": {
            "subsidence": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "defective_drains": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "damp": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "fungal_insect_infestation": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "structual_defects": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
                }
            },
        "radon": {
            "gas": {
                "measured": null,
                "measurement": {
                    "copy": null,
                    "below_action_level": null,
                    "above_action_level_details": null,
                    "remedial_action": null,
                    "remedial_action_details": null
                    }
                }
            },
        "epc": {
            "copy": null
        },
        "sustainablecertificate": {
            "copy": null
        },
        "greendeal": {
            "green_deal": null,
            "details": {
                "details": null,
                "copy": null
                }
            },
        "japaneseknotweed": {
            "affected": null,
            "plan": {
                "in_place": null,
                "copy": null
                }
            }
        },
    "mining": {
        "description": {
            "question": null
        },
        "area": {
            "damage": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "claim": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "previous_owner_claim": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "coal_board": {
                "upload": null
                }
            }
        },
    "general": {
        "description": {
            "council_tax_band": null,
            "council_tax_amount": null,
            "keep_telephone_number": null,
            "burgled": null
        },
        "insurance": {
            "question": null,
            "anomalies": {
                "abnormal_premiums": null,
                "high_excesses": null,
                "unusual_conditions": null,
                "refused": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "claims": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
                }
            },
        "gift_under_value": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "meter_readings": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "services_issues": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "parking": {
            "arrangements": null,
            "zonal": null
        },
        "covenants": {
            "question": null,
            "details": null
        },
        "confirm": {
            "rubbish_removal": null,
            "light_fittings": null,
            "removal_care": null,
            "keys_and_alarm": null
        },
        "propertytitle": {
        },
        "property": {
            "locks": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "windows": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "lavatory": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "kitchen": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "radiators": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "heating_hot_water": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "gas_appliances": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "gas_electrical_circuitry": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
            },
            "gas_electrical_other": {
                "question": null,
                "details": null
                }
            }
        },
    "uploads": {
        "description": {
        },
        "notices": {
            "sentrec": {
            }
        },
        "guarantees": {
            "foundation_newbuild_evidence": {
            },
            "damp_course_evidence": {
            },
            "glazing_roofing_evidence": {
            },
            "electrical_evidence": {
            },
            "roofing_evidence": {
            },
            "rot_infestation_evidence": {
            },
            "central_heating_evidence": {
            },
            "underpinning_evidence": {
            },
            "other_evidence": {
            },
            "written_details_evidence": {
            }
        },
        "central_heating": {
            "certificate": {
            },
            "benchmark_scheme_logbook": {
            }
        },
        "services": {
            "water_charge": {
            },
            "sewerage_account": {
            },
            "septic_cesspit_drainage_regulations": {
            },
            "septic_cesspit_drainage_plan": {
            },
            "electricity_certificate": {
            },
            "electricity_rewire_certificates_bs7671": {
            },
            "electricity_rewire_certificates_compliance": {
            },
            "electricity_rewire_certificates_completion": {
            }
        },
        "neighbours": {
            "notice": {
            }
        },
        "occupiers": {
            "rights_vacation_evidence": {
            },
            "rights_tenancy_agreement": {
            }
        },
        "changes": {
            "building_works": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                }
            },
            "change_use": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                }
            },
            "sub_division": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                }
            },
            "conversion": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                }
            },
            "business_activity": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                }
            },
            "underpinning": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                }
            },
            "solar_panels": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                },
                "lease": {
                }
            },
            "replace_window_roof": {
                "permission": {
                },
                "regulations_approved": {
                },
                "insurance_policy": {
                },
                "certificate_regulations": {
                },
                "listed_building": {
                }
            },
            "central_heating": {
                "certificate_regulations": {
                }
            }
        },
        "conservatory": {
            "details_building_approval": {
            }
        },
        "planning": {
            "buildingcontrol_elec_works_certificate": {
            },
            "buildingcontrol_gas_installation_certificate": {
            },
            "tree": {
                "preservation": {
                }
            }
        },
        "environmental": {
            "flooding_risk": {
            },
            "radontestresults": {
            },
            "epc": {
            },
            "sustainabilitycertificate": {
            }
        },
        "mining": {
            "coal_board_info": {
            }
        }
    },
    "instructions": {
        "confirmation": {
            "authority": null
        },
        "completed": {
            "name": null,
            "date": null
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just run your posted JSON through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) - there is a duplicate `consent` field in the structure. It's in the `changes.replace.window_roof.title` object.

Comment: Thank you... I ran it through JSONLint and that reported valid JSON.

Comment: This just tripped me up, too. JSONLint was telling me it was valid and I didn't think twice. JSLint told me I had accidentally put a duplicate field in.